# Enriching prometheus Response on while any api fails

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus

In Spring boot i have one Rest api with a controller "/my" . In "my controller i am calling 3 apis  : /a, /b ,c

when any api is down i am throwing LocalHttpClientErrorException .

Now when i am exposing prometheus metrics it is showing the count which is fine .. but can i enrich this to show which api is actually throwing exception

Getting response

> http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="LocalHttpClientErrorException",method="GET",outcome="CLIENT_ERROR",status="404",uri="/my",}
>   3.032826704

Expected Response

> http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="LocalHttpClientErrorException
>   at Api
>   A",method="GET",outcome="CLIENT_ERROR",status="404",uri="/my/a",}
>   3.032826704

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can enrich your metric with your own label. You didn't share the code, so I can't write an exact answer to your question, but you should look into **WebFluxTagsProvider** or **MeterFilter**.

I will update this, once you update the question.